# How do I recapture lossless data from input via encoding

Tags: c++, file-io, bit-manipulation

I am having a tough time recreating a file from a compressed form I have created. I need it to be lossless. I'm sure I have the data, and I'm sure because I have full size output to the proxied source target. In fact it is always more. I am also having trouble stopping a loop. I don't know what to put. Another question I have, is what does (x & 7) do for recreating data? It seems itd just muck with what I have.

i have this code for compressing:

```
    while (top > 0)
    {
        
        str_xweight += bitset<4>(top).to_string();
        top >>= 4;
        // long long unsigned int u32t = pow(2,63);
        uint64_t u8t = top;
        top = 0;
        while ((u8t >> 3) > 0)
        {
            str_xweight += "1";
            str_xweight += bitset<3>(u8t).to_string();
            u8t >>= 3;
        }
        str_xweight += "0";
        str_xweight += bitset<3>(u8t).to_string();
    }
```

The lines above get used numerous times before i output. I add a '-$' to it too. Before the accumulated data. I do not end the data with the mark there, tho.

I have this code for decompressing:

```
    bool chk = false;
    for (i = 0; section_str.length() > 4 ; )
    {
        if (!chk)
            full_comp += section_str.substr(0,4);
        else
            return full_comp;
        section_str = section_str.substr(4);
        while (section_str.front() == '1')
        {
            full_comp += section_str.substr(1,3);
            section_str = section_str.substr(4);
            cout << "." << flush;
            chk = true;
        }
        if (chk && section_str.front() == '0')
        {
            cout << "?" << flush;
            full_comp += section_str.substr(1,3);
            section_str = section_str.substr(4);
            chk = false;
        }
    }
```

Now, I have this code for getting the files compressed data.

```
    uint64_t buf_cntA = 0, buf_cntB = 2, cntAB= 0, return_len = 0;
    string binary_return_str = "";
    ofstream out {filename_str.c_str(), std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::trunc };
    for (size_t i = 0; (full_size > buf_cntB + 8) ; i++)
    {
        buf_cntA = buf.find("-$",buf_cntB);
        buf_cntB = buf.find("-$",buf_cntA);
        string buf_keep = buf.substr(buf_cntA+2,buf_cntB);
        buf_cntB += 2;
        if (buf_keep.length() == 0)
        {
            out << "        " << flush;
            // binary_return_str.clear();
            continue;
        }
        string return_str = retrieve(buf_keep);
        binary_return_str = bitsToBytes(return_str, return_len);
        
        out << binary_return_str << flush;
        binary_return_str.clear();
        
        cout << "\rLeft: " << (full_size - buf_cntB) << "         \r\n" << flush;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your compression/decompression scheme have a formal description somewhere?

Comment: x & 7 results with only 3 least significant bits of x. Rest of your question is probably unanswerable as it is very hard to reverse engineer idea of a program from random (and definitely buggy, otherwise you would not ask)  slices of code of it.

Comment: @Botje I can make one. I've never written a white paper though.

Comment: Doesn't have to be a white paper, but a non-code description of your (intended) algorithm so we don't have to reverse engineer it from your code

Comment: @Botje could we go to chat?